# How to change zoom dynamically with many map marker in sebm google maps?

Tags: angular

my html code is

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [mapTypeControl]="true">
  <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let device of devices;" [latitude]="device.latitude" [longitude]="device.longitude" [label]="device.name">
  </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

In `sebm-google-map` I can find `fitBounds` but do not know how to apply it. I have many devices with map markers so when I load that map component it will show all devices on the map.

Comment: I am new to angular 2 can anyone help me to fix it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using (I think) an old version of angular-google-maps.

The attribute `sebm-google-map` is renamed to `agm-map`.

**Example**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
</agm-map>
```

---

The [fitBounds](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/57600bbd158316706538dc2e3f6b3a803ad726dc/packages/core/directives/map.ts#L183) attribute is a `LatLngBoundsLiteral` object.

You can define the bounds like this:

```
let bounds = {
  east: 12.345,
  north: 23.456,
  south: 34.567,
  west: 45.678
}
```